# Reducing variance in A/B testing with CUPED

Tags: python, variance, reduction

Consider:

```
def get_cuped_adjusted(A_before, B_before, A_after, B_after):
    cv = cov([A_after + B_after, A_before + B_before])
    theta = cv[0, 1] / cv[1, 1]
    mean_before = mean(A_before + B_before)
    A_after_adjusted = [after - (before - mean_before) * theta for after, before in zip(A_after, A_before)]
    B_after_adjusted = [after - (before - mean_before) * theta for after, before in zip(B_after, B_before)]
    return A_after_adjusted, B_after_adjusted
```

What does the above code do?

Basically, I want to reduce variance in A/B testing using the CUPED method.

For reference: *[Reducing variance in A/B testing with CUPED](https://bytepawn.com/reducing-variance-in-ab-testing-with-cuped.html)*

Comment: It adjusts your post-period data in each group using information from pre-period information (a single covariate, usually the same metric) so that the diff between these new adjusted values is approximately unbiased and should have significantly less variance if the pre-period covariate is correlated with the post-period metric.